# Odds on repeat draw of same number in 10 draws

Tags: probability

I'm having a discusion with a friend about odds.  We disagree on the formula to determine the odds of the follow scenario.

Start with a set of $12$ cards in a deck.
One card is drawn from that deck and recorded.
The card is replaced in the deck.
The deck is shuffled.
Repeat $10$ times.

How do you calculate the odds of getting the same card $4$ times out of $10$ draws?

I have been using $1/12$ or $0.0833$ for any card multiplied by this same number for each repeat, then multiply the odds of not getting that card, $11/12$ or $0.917$ times for the non-repeat card.  In otherwords, ($0.0833$ x itself $4$ times) x ($0.917$ x itself $6$ times).  Is this correct?

Comment: That would be the probability of selecting a particular card four times followed by different card six times, in that order. You must account for different orderings. Also, you have not accounted for there being $12$ different cards to get $4$ times.

Comment: Exactly four, or at least four?  And I assume that a situation where you draw each of two cards five times each also satisfies the condition.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, are we picking a card first to be the "target card" then repeating $10$ times? Or is this first draw counted as the first of ten draws? Or do we want to find where any card is repeated four times?

Comment: Exactly four of any particular draw in any order, just four repeats of the same card.  It doesn't have to be the first card which then repeats three more times, it could be the third card which repeat draws on 4, 9, and 10 draws.  Or the same card could come up draws 7,8,9,and 10.

Comment: Remy, how does the order of each random draw matter?  If the odds of drawing one card are 1/12 and not that card are 11/12, why isn't it multiplying those odds for each draw?  When flipping a coin, it's 50/50 for each flip, but 0.5x0.5 for the odds of two tails.  As far as I understand the odds of getting two tails and one heads in three flips is the same whether it is tth tht or htt.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Total outcomes : $12^{10}$

Favorable outcomes for getting the card 1 for the 4 first draws and different cards for the 6 remaining draws: $1^4 \times 11^6$

Favorable outcomes for getting the card 1 exactly 4 times out of 10 draws in any order: $\binom{10}{4} \times11^6$

Favorable outcomes for getting the card 1 at least 4 times out of 10 draws in any order: $\sum\limits_{i=4}^{10} \binom{10}{i} \times11^{10-i}$

Favorable outcomes for getting any card exactly 4 times for any draws: NOT equal to $12\times\binom{10}{4} \times11^6$ because many cases overlap and do no count as new valid outcomes. It is not easy to generalize at this point and you need to either carefully count every distinct valid outcomes or find a trick and transform the problem.

Probability = $\frac{\mathrm{Favorable \ outcomes}}{\mathrm{Total \ outcomes}}$